# Convert a string into JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json assigned to variable as:

```
var a = "[{a:123}]";
```

Now if I do `a[0]` it gives result as `[`. On doing `a = JSON.parse(a)` it gives error as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2`

How can i convert a into `a = [{a:123}];` ?

Comment: That's because the object in the array is not valid JSON. Now if it was this `var a = '[{"a":123}]'` it would work. Try using a [JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't have a valid JSON.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2

This error complains about the character "a" which is not valid here. See http://www.json.org/

You could in theory achieve your goal by using `eval` but this is highly insecure because you can evaluate any code that is present in your string so I wouldn't recommend that.

You have to either make sure that the JSON you get is valid, or you may need to preprocess the string before passing it to JSON.parse if the format cannot be changed.

By the way, contrary to another answer here that was upvoted for some reason, there is no such thing as `Array.parse`:

```
$ node -e 'Array.parse()'
[eval]:1
Array.parse()
      ^    
TypeError: Array.parse is not a function
```

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace :

```
var a = "[{a:123}]";
```

by :

```
var a = "[{\"a\":123}]";
```

Comment: Yes this worked for me, i changed the data query which was building the object. Thanks!